# Random post_id at wp_insert_post

Tags: posts, wp-insert-post

How I can use an absolute random post_id in wp-admin at `wp_insert_post`? I need stored in wp-admin a unique random post_id, but not I have only: 2210, 2212, 2214. As I understand it, this will not work because of the uniqueness of the keys in the database.

Comment: the post ID is the primary key of the table and cannot be modified. if you want a random and custom value for each post, you can set it in a post meta ([update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta))

Comment: What is the intention behind? Can you elaborate your goal?

Comment: the essence is this: when a user submits a request, a post is created in the admin panel: name, email, etc. and the user gets a unique number in the system by which he can find himself, for these purposes I need use number and slug name - random which consists of 10 digits, now in wp-admin via wp_insert_post i can get only short number